# Can't rm formats after conversion

Tags: rm, images, mogrify

How can I fix the following command, so that all files with the format specified with the rm command are deleted?

```
#!/bin/bash
mogrify -verbose -format webp -quality 70 *.jpg *.jpeg *.JPEG *.JPG *.png *.PNG && rm --verbose *.jpg *.jpeg *.JPEG *.JPG *.png *.PNG
$SHELL
```

The command successfully converts the images to webp, but rm doesn't delete any of the original files.

I get the following errors after converting to webp:

```
mogrify-im6.q16: unable to open image `*.jpeg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2874.
mogrify-im6.q16: unable to open image `*.JPG': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2874.
mogrify-im6.q16: unable to open image `*.JPG': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2874.
mogrify-im6.q16: unable to open image `*.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2874.
mogrify-im6.q16: unable to open image `*.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2874.
mogrify-im6.q16: unable to open image `*.PNG': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2874.
mogrify-im6.q16: unable to open image `*.PNG': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2874.
```

Comment: Do ALL of the shell globs expand to at least one valid filename - or do you see things like `unable to open image '*.JPG': No such file or directory`? If the latter, then probably `mogrify` is exiting with non-zero status

Comment: If you run `mogrify ... && echo exit status $?`  presumably after a successful conversion the exit status is unexpectedly non-zero? Does the documentation for `mogrify` (ie `man mogrify`) say anything about its exit status?

Comment: @steeldriver I added the errors I get to the question.

Comment: So you're getting errors from mogrify, which means it'll be returning an error status. Which in turn means your `rm` won't be executed

Comment: Next time please include error messages when you ask a question. They're important - that's why they're reported to you

Comment: @roaima Sorry, should have included the error messages in original post. Your solution worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this `bash` option to your script, before you use the wildcard patterns

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

This tells the shell to remove patterns that don't match, rather then leaving them as literals. So from your example, `*.png` will be removed rather than left as a five character filename starting with an asterisk (which probably doesn't exist).